# InDesign script: footnotes loosing their style

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Ok, I know this had been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235029/indesign-script-for-footnotes-losing-text-styles) but no clear answer had been provided. I often need to import XML files into InDesign, many footnotes included. Of course, InD is not able to use tags automatically in this case. This script works well except all footnotes loose their styles. I know it could be because of the `contents` on lines 27 and 35. It is needed to use `move` instead. Unfortunately, I am not good at JavaScript and can't figure out how to implement that properly.

```
Application.prototype.main = function(){
if ( this.documents.length <= 0 ) return;
var tg = this.selection[0] || this.activeDocument;
if( 'appliedFont' in tg ) tg = tg.parent;
if( tg.constructor == TextFrame ){ tg = tg.parentStory ; }
if(! ('findGrep' in tg) ) return;

var fnPatterns = ["@foot@([\\s\\S]*?)@foot@", "@footnotes_begin@([\\s\\S]*?)@footnotes_end@"];
var count = 0;

for(patterCounter = 0; patterCounter < fnPatterns.length; patterCounter++){ 
    fnPattern = fnPatterns[patterCounter]; 

    var fnFinds = (function(){              
        this.findGrepPreferences = this.changeGrepPreferences = null;
            this.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = fnPattern;            
            var ret = tg.findGrep();
            this.findGrepPreferences = this.changeGrepPreferences = null;

        return ret;
    }).call(this);


    var fnFind, fnText, rg = new RegExp(fnPattern), ip, fnParent, fn, count;

    while( fnFind=fnFinds.pop() ){
        fnText = fnFind.contents.match(rg)[1];


        fnParent = fnFind.parent.getElements()[0];
        ip = fnFind.insertionPoints[0].index
        try {
            fnFind.remove();
            fn = fnParent.footnotes.add(LocationOptions.BEFORE, fnParent.insertionPoints[ip]);
            fn.texts[0].insertionPoints[-1].contents = fnText;
            ++count;
        }
            catch(_){}
    }
}

alert((count)? (count+" footnote(s) successfully added."): "No footnote added. Make sure you use the relevant pattern.");
}
app.doScript('app.main();', ScriptLanguage.javascript,
undefined, UndoModes.entireScript, app.activeScript.displayName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **exactly the same** as in the question you linked to: you are manipulating a plain string translation in Javascript, not the native InDesign text object itself. Use `move` and `duplicate` methods on the `text` property of the found list instead.

A basic solution is to use

```
    fn = fnFind.footnotes.add(LocationOptions.AFTER, fnFind.insertionPoints[-1]);
    fnFind.texts[0].move (LocationOptions.AT_END, fn.texts[0]);
```

but this will copy the start and end markers as well. It takes a bit more to remove them; I based the following adjustments in your original script on your GREP patterns, but it may be safer to build an explicit list of `prefix`/`suffix` pairs, as you also can use them to construct the GREP searches.

The next problem, then, is if you *copy* (`duplicate`, in InDesign's DOM) the found text, the original "found" text will now have the footnote attached to it! This is because one line earlier, you *add the footnote to the "found" text*. So you cannot use a simple `remove` to delete it; again, you need to manipulate the `text` object, but this time through its individual characters. My last adjusted line 'selects' the `fnFind` texts, minus its very last character (which is the newly added footnote), and deletes it.

```
var fnFind, fnPrefix,fnSuffix, rg = new RegExp(fnPattern), ip, fnParent, fn, count;

while( fnFind=fnFinds.pop() ){
    fnPrefix = fnFind.contents.match(/^@[^@]+@/)[0];
    fnSuffix = fnFind.contents.match(/@[^@]+@/)[0];

    // add footnote
    fn = fnFind.footnotes.add(LocationOptions.AFTER, fnFind.insertionPoints[-1]);
    // duplicate the text
    fnFind.texts[0].characters.itemByRange(fnPrefix.length,fnFind.texts[0].characters.length-fnSuffix.length-1).duplicate(LocationOptions.AT_END, fn.texts[0]);
    // remove the original
    fnFind.characters.itemByRange(0,fnFind.characters.length-2).remove();
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: You made my day! Thanks a lot! The only one thing I had to add is to remove the catch(_){} line. It was still throwing errors because of that. Have no clue if this was properly done.

Comment: Thanks, have just figured out how to use that. I am into Ruby very much, this inspires me, maybe I could learn more about JavaScript, too :)